# How do I create a foreign key in sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't get my program to use a foreign key for some unbeknown reason. I have read other questions related to this but cant find an answer that works. I tried the PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON, but instead i get a syntax error for "foreign_keys". I also tried removing this and running the program again and instead got an error saying the column I'm trying to create doesn't exist

```
import sqlite3
import os
import random
from tkinter import *
import uuid
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON

conn = sqlite3.connect('MyComputerScience.db')
c = conn.cursor() 
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            UserID text PRIMARY KEY,
            FName text,
            SName text,
            username text,
            password varchar,
            userType text)""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes (
            ClassID PRIMARY KEY,
            FOREIGN KEY (User) REFERENCES users(UserID)))""")





 FOREIGN KEY (User) REFERENCES users(UserID)))""")
sqlite3.OperationalError: unknown column "User" in foreign key definition
```

Comment: The PRAGMA line should not be in the Python code as it is not valid Python (hence the SyntaxError). Instead, execute that line immediately after creating the connection (`conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = on")`). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427284/1441112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the fields in the table before using them as a foreign key.

As you did not add a field `User` to your table, you got the error:

> unknown column "User" in foreign key definition

To fix the error, add `User` to your table definition

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes (
            ClassID PRIMARY KEY,
            User text,
            FOREIGN KEY (User) REFERENCES users(UserID)))""")
```

However, I would question the design. The table `classes` would only be able to relate one user per class. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS classes (
            ClassID PRIMARY KEY,
            FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) REFERENCES users(UserID)))""")
```

That's the correct syntax but this way you set as foreign key your primary key. Maybe you wanted to use another field.